# Redemption - Shared mailbox / store not found

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

I have the following code.

```
var rdoSession = new RDOSession();
rdoSession.MAPIOBJECT = explorer.Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
var mailbox = rdoSession.GetSharedMailbox("sharedmail@company.com");
var inbox = mailbox.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

But I get the following error

> Could not find the store DN from GetSharedMailbox(..)

but the store is listed when I iterate rdoSession.Stores.

Any suggestions will be appreciated in this regard. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this means Redemption could not retrieve the specified user's autodiscover xml since it has no credentials to do so. Is using `RDOSession.Creadentials.Add` an option?

Comment: Thx for reply, I tried my AD account - but still same error? Perhaps the server name is wrong - outlook.server.local?

Comment: Send a message to redemption (at) dimastr dot com - and I will send you the debug version of the dll.